# How can I resize a partition without moving it using partition manager (gparted doesn't work with KDE)?

Tags: partitioning, kde

I want to resize the current Kubuntu partition, but  KDE partition manager apparently only offers the resize-and-move option. I'm afraid the next boot will fail if I move that partition, correct?
I can't use gparted.
Thank you.

Comment: "(gparted doesn't work with KDE)" yes it does. "I can't use gparted."
 why not?

Comment: I tried to install it from live-disk, but it wouldn't launch. And the description says it's a Gnome software so I thought that was the reason.

Comment: I tried it again, doesn't work.  Muon downloaded and installed it but gparted doesn't appear in the list of applications and it won't start from the icon in the Muon window.   Any help for partition manager?

Comment: I always use a gparted live dvd (  http://gparted.org/livecd.php )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KDE has [QtParted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtParted) (mind `q` instead of `g` and the extra `t`).

[image]

Mind you: GParted also works in KDE.

---

I myself made a [GParted live DVD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) that I carry around. That might be an easier option.

Comment: Thank you so much for your persistence. You are right of course, gparted works in KDE. I don't know why Muon didn't get it running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted why not? I am also under Kubuntu now, works for me.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
sudo gparted
```

Move and/or resize your Kubuntu partition.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!! Everything worked like a charm, gparted installed and worked without trouble.    I'm not used to working with konsole (the old MS-DOS days are long gone) so I couldn't have done it without you...    It is really great that guys like you offer their time to help newbies like me.